# Search for Firstname or Last name in column formatted as "Firstname Lastname"

Tags: php, mysql

In a table I'm working with the full_name column has the format "Firstname Lastname"

Eg. "John West"

I'm using this:

```
$q="John";

$sql = "SELECT full_name  FROM wp_users where full_name like '$q%' order by display_name ASC";
```

That works ok and "John West" is returned.

But if I make $q equal to "West" and try to search by the surname then nothing gets returned. Is there an mysql statement that I can use to do this better?

Comment: Use wildcards on both sides. `%$q%`. The search runs a bit slower, but will look for the match anywhere in the field.

Comment: Tried that and it was bringing up people that didn't have the contents of $q in their names.

Answer (score 1):

try using a proper wildchar concat for your condition

```
$sql = "SELECT full_name  
          FROM wp_users where full_name like concat('%', $q,'%') 
          ORDER BY display_name ASC";
```

or

```
$q = '%John%';

$sql = "SELECT full_name  
          FROM wp_users where full_name like '$q' 
          ORDER BY display_name ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

put percentage on both sides

```
    $q="John";

$sql = "SELECT full_name  FROM wp_users where full_name like '%$q%' order by display_name ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
$q="John";

$sql = "SELECT full_name  FROM wp_users where full_name like '$q%' or full_name like '$%q'  order by display_name ASC";
```